# pyfilesystem2, FSTestCases: testing a filesystem

Tags: python, testing, filesystems

I've implemented a filesystem using pyfilesystem2 and now I want to test it. I have my own unit test cases, but pyfilesystem2 provides its own test cases, which I'd be happy to run, but... I have no idea how. The documentation only says how to create a tester class, but not a word on how to invoke the testing - [see for yourself](https://pyfilesystem2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/implementers.html#testing-filesystems). help() function doesn't help as well - there are almost no docstrings in there.

Ok, but there is a list of available methods, right? Yeah, I tried creating a tester object and then invoking its test_basic() method, but it fails because of some internal errors...

```
(env) qvasic@qzenbook:~/code/filesyst$ python3 dropboxfs.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dropboxfs.py", line 630, in <module>
    t.test_basic()
  File "/mnt/d/code/filesyst/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/fs/test.py", line 349, in test_basic
    repr(self.fs)
AttributeError: 'TestDropBoxFS' object has no attribute 'fs'
(env) qvasic@qzenbook:~/code/filesyst$ python3 dropboxfs.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dropboxfs.py", line 629, in <module>
    t.test_basic()
  File "/mnt/d/code/filesyst/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/fs/test.py", line 349, in test_basic
    repr(self.fs)
AttributeError: 'TestDropBoxFS' object has no attribute 'fs'
```

(I know there is an implementation for DropBox, it's just an excercise for me.)

Googling doesn't help either, because everything points back to the pyfilesystem2 documentation, which is lacking...

Can anybody give me a hint what to do? How do I run those test cases?

PS. Coming from C/C++ languages to Python is frustrating in terms of documentation. May be I just don't understand the paradigm, but it looks lacking A LOT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyFilesystem uses the [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) module in the stdlib for tests. To simplify running the tests, I use `nose` which you can install as follows:

`pip install nose`

Then you can use the following command to run the tests.

`nosetests -v`

BTW Your post comes across as venting. You will always get a better response if you keep your questions on topic, without complaining.

You could also ask the PyFilesystem developers directly via the [PyFilesystem Issues](https://github.com/pyfilesystem/pyfilesystem2/issues) on Github.

Comment: Thanks!
You are right, but if there is a prerequisite (like unittest module in this case) for any piece of documentation, it should be mentioned. It's all I am saying.